# Check if a character in a string is a 1 or a 0

Tags: c#

I am recieveing a string via a com port that looks like this *000000, or *110101, or anything in between. Each character represents the status of a relay on a PCB I have and the first character after the asterisk represents the first relay and so on. I need to check each character seperatly if it is a 1 or a 0 and then set a label to either ON or OFF accordingly.

My code would be something like this:

```
if(char 1 == "1")
{

    label4.Text = "ON";    
}
else
{
    label4.Text = "OFF";
}
```

and so on down the line for all 6 characters. But I don't know how to seperate each character.

Thanks!

Comment: use string.substring(startpos,length) to get a substring and act accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean like indexing ? `string a = "10"; char one = a[0]; char two = a[1];` It's hard to understand your question, which also contains a syntax error on line 1.

Comment: char[] chArray = yourstring.ToCharArray(); will just return your string as a char arrray to work with..

Comment: @Flowerking: Why create an array for no reason? Just use the indexer.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like you want to use the [indexer on `String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx) to extract a single `char`:

```
string text = "*110101"; // Wherever you get this from...
label4.Text = text[1] == '1' ? "ON" : "OFF";
label5.Text = text[2] == '1' ? "ON" : "OFF";
label6.Text = text[3] == '1' ? "ON" : "OFF";
label7.Text = text[4] == '1' ? "ON" : "OFF";
label8.Text = text[5] == '1' ? "ON" : "OFF";
label9.Text = text[6] == '1' ? "ON" : "OFF";
```

This assumes that you're happy for the label text to be set to "OFF" for any value other than '1'. (As noted in comments, you use double quotes for *string* literals, but single quotes for *character* literals.)

Note how I've used the conditional operator here to simplify the code: if you want to basically choose between two values ("ON" and "OFF") based on a condition, the conditional operator is much simpler than an `if`/`else`. Don't overdo it, of course, but it's worth becoming familiar with.

However, I would also suggest you might want to put the relevant labels into a collection. Then you could use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    toggles[i].Text = text[i + 1] == '1' ? "ON" : "OFF";
}
```

Comment: OP, note the single quotes around the `1`s to specify a char rather than a string.

Answer (score 4):

You already have the string?

You can use indexers on the string object to access the characters.

Example:

```
string s = "110110";
if (s[3] == '0') label4.Text = "ON";
```

Comment: Except that that will set it the other way round (1 should mean ON, not OFF) and it *won't* set it to "OFF" otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

you can get specific char by :

> string relaysStatus = "100110"; 
>   char c = relaysStatus.ElementAt(0);

or you can convert then all to bool list:

> var relays = relaysStatus.Select(q => q == '1').ToList();

Comment: While the second approach might be useful, I see no benefit in using `ElementAt` instead of the indexer on string.

Comment: Yes Sure me too but that was his question, i should answer him first then suggest better solution

Comment: Where in the question did it ask to use LINQ? It asked to get at a single character in a string - and the indexer (e.g. `text[0]`) is simply a better way of doing that, IMO. It's more efficient and more readable. What do you think the benefit of using ElementAt is?

Answer (score 1):

Moving further, you can create extension method for converting chars to On/Off strings:

```
public static class CharExtensions
{
    public static string ToOnOff(this char ch)
    {
        return (ch == '1') ? "On" : "Off";
    }
}
```

After that you can use it (pretty clean code):

```
label1.Text = input[0].ToOnOff(); 
label2.Text = input[1].ToOnOff();
```

UPDATE: I think good point to check both '0' and '1' values. But it depends on your input string.

```
public static class CharExtensions
{
    public static string ToOffOn(this char ch)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case '0' : return "Off";
            case '1': return "On";
            default:
                return ch.ToString(); // Or rise exception
        }            
    }
}
```